# jQuery CSS 'or' selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I am trying to select elements of a (certain class || another class) with the same selector. How can I go about doing that?

Currently, I have:

```
$(".class1 .class2").each(function(idx, el) {... });
```

however, that only selects elements that match both classes, not one or the other.

How can I select elements that match one or both of the classes, with the same selector?

Comment: `however, that only selects elements that match both classes, not one or the other.` No it's not. It looks for an element with class `class1` then find it's children with a class of `class2`.

Comment: doing this: `.class1.class2`  (no space) would select elements that have have both classes.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".class1,.class2")
```

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: As a note, it isn't an `OR` or anything, just creates a union of elements matched.

Answer (score 9):

```
$(".class1,.class2").each(function(idx, el) {... });
```

put a comma within the same selector string.

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/